# image not saved in folder

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload

Hello i have a crud operation and i have this code to upload an image for product but the image is not saved either in mysql or in folder host.

```
?php
 include("includes/db.php");
 $msg = "";
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $target = "images/".basename($_FILES['poza']['name']);
 $image = $_FILES['poza']['name'];
 $nume = $_POST['nume'];
 $editor = $_POST['editor'];
 $pozitie = $_POST['pozitie'];
 $pret = $_POST['pret'];
 $cat = $_POST['cat'];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO produse (poza, titlu, descriere,pozitie,pret,categorie) 
 VALUES ('$image','$nume','$editor', '$pozitie','$pret','$cat')";
 mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

  // mut poza in folder

 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['poza']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
  $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data- 
     dismiss='alert'>×</button>
                <div class='alert-icon'>
                 <i class='icon-check'></i>
                </div>
                <div class='alert-message'>
                  <span><strong>Success!</strong> Produsul a fost adaugat! 
          </span>
                </div>
              </div>";
      }else{
         $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' 
           role='alert'>
               <button type='button' class='close' data- 
                    dismiss='alert'>×</button>
                <div class='alert-icon'>
                 <i class='icon-close'></i>
                </div>
                <div class='alert-message'>
                  <span><strong>Eroare!</strong> Produsul nu a fost salvat! 
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>";
        }
            header('location: index.php');
       }


       ?>
```

target is my path to folder but in my folder images is empty like mysql database the same emtpy.

HTML is on modal boostrap here is the code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">


  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">titlu</h4>
        </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="" action="add.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="">descriere</label>
               <textarea name="editor" class="ckeditor" id="continut" 
                rows="8" cols="80" value=""><?php echo $row['continut'];?> 
               </textarea>
         <label for="">poza</label>
          <input type="file" name="poza" value="">
          <label for="">Titlu</label>
                  <input type="text" name="nume" value="">
                  <label for="">Pozitie</label>
                  <input type="text" name="pozitie" value="">
                  <label for="">pret</label>
                  <input type="text" name="pret" value="">
                  <label for="">pret</label>
                  <select name="cat" id="cat">
                 <option value="">Selecteaza categoria</option>
                 <option value="1">ACE DE CUSUT</option>
                 <option value="2">ATA & PAMBLICA</option>
                 <option value="3">FERMOAR</option>
                 <option value="4">NASTURI</option>
                 <option value="5">ALTE ACCESORII</option>
         </select>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Salveaza</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
     dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don`t know how to check the array $_FILES i will try but i can`t understand i made some changes to the path and i still the same.

Comment: check if the $_FILES array is populated

Comment: where is the form/html for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the form to be formatted properly, primarily the `<form>` tag:

```
<!-- needs "multipart/form-data" -->
<form action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

---

**Below are suggestions on other implementations; ignore if you don't care**

Other issues beyond that you need to make sure the folder where the file is being saved to is created with correct permissions, you need to parameterize your mysql query, and you need to make sure your upload has enough memory in your php ini:

I suggest you use the OOP version of mysqli or use PDO instead. Binding is much more straight forward.

I would also suggest using a root-folder config file for constants and consistency:

**/config.php**

```
<?php
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
# Sometimes defines are helpful
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
# Set your image folder
define('IMAGE_DIR', ROOT_DIR.DS.'images');
# Set an include folder
define('INCLUDES', ROOT_DIR.DS.'includes');
# Set an functions folder
define('FUNCTIONS', INCLUDES.DS.'functions');
# Start session
session_start();
# Add the database
require(INCLUDES.DS."db.php");
```

**/includes/db.php**

```
<?php
# Create an OOP connection instead of a functional connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Create an observer to contain your action listener

**/includes/functions/imageObserver.php**

```
<?php
# Inject the DB and make sure the system messages are passed
function imageObserver($conn, &$msg)
{
    # Stop if no action
    if(!isset($_POST['action']))
        return false;
    # Stop if action not set
    if($_POST['action'] != 'upload_image')
        return false;
    # Make sure the image folder is created
    if(!is_dir(IMAGE_DIR))
        mkdir(IMAGE_DIR, 0755, true);
    # You may want to do a file check here incase someone uploads something
    # they shouldn't

    # Set image name
    $image   = $_FILES['poza']['name'];
    # Set the path
    $target  = IMAGE_DIR.DS.$image;
    # Move the file
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['poza']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        extract($_POST);
        # Create the string, use "?" in place of values
        $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO produse (`poza`, `titlu`, `descriere`, `pozitie`, `pret`, `categorie`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        # Bind the values to the statement question marks
        $query->bind_param('ssssss', $image, $nume, $editor, $pozitie, $pret, $cat);
        # Execute the query
        $query->execute();
        # You should also do an error check here

        $msg['success'] = true;
    }
    else
        $msg['error'] = true;
}
```

**/whatever-this-page-is.php**

```
<?php
# add the config
require(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."config.php");
# add the observer function
require(FUNCTIONS.DS."imageObserver.php");
# Set the messages array
$msg = [];
# Add our listener
imageObserver($conn, &$msg);
# Check if something actually took place, redirect if not
if(empty($msg)) {
    header('index.php');
    # You have to exit on this header
    exit;
}
?>

<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>
    <div class='alert-icon'>
        <i class='icon-check'></i>
    </div>
    <div class='alert-message'>
        <span><strong><?php echo (!empty($msg['success']))? 'Success' : 'Eroare' ?>!</strong> Produsul a fost <?php echo (!empty($msg['success']))? 'adaugat' : 'salvat' ?>!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your form then needs to have an `enctype` as `multipart/form-data` and you should put an action name because you might do other form submits with the key name `submit`:

```
<form class="" action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- make the action name here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload_image" />
    <input type="file" name="poza" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Now!" />
</form>
```

Finally, you should see how much memory your instance is using in your `php.ini` file, it may not be enough *(this is just example settings, you might be fine or not)*:

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M 
max_execution_time = 3000
max_input_time = 3000
memory_limit = 64M
```